# AEM 6.3, wcm.io: mocking LiveRelationshipManager

Tags: mocking, adobe, aem, sling

I want to test a service that in itself references the LiveRelationshipManager:

```
@Reference
private LiveRelationshipManager liveRelationshipManager;
```

The implementation of the LiveRelationshipManager is hidden, I only have the api. How can I register it in my aemContext like for example my own LanaguageService:

```
aemContext.registerInjectActivateService(new LanguageService());
```

One solution I found was creating a mock class myself:

```
@Component(service = LiveRelationshipManager.class)
public class MockLiveRelationshipManager implements LiveRelationshipManager {
```

But how do I prevent it from being used in my real application and only in my unit tests? Or is there a better way?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the mock class only in your tests you should **not** annotate it with `@Component`.
Just create the mock implementation and then use

```
context.registerService(LiveRelationshipManager.class, new MockLiveRelationshipManager())
```

to add it to your context.